# Making a detailed archive-template page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress page, where I'm displaying the 5 most-recent posts on the frontpage, and below the posts is a "browse all" button.

Looking around at google I found that the best way to achieve this, was through making a page with a template, where I could display the information I would get from fetching the posts through the `wp_get_archives();` function.

This lists the title of all my blog posts as li's, which is okay, since I need the titles any way, but how can I make this archive a little more detailed by also retrieving values such as a thumbnail, the content or even custom-fields generated with the ACF plugin?

The `wp_get_archives();` function hardly seems customizable to me, so I'm looking for another way to retrieve information from my blogposts, so I can print this out as a more detailed archive.

Can anyone point me towards how to retrieve more information from this function, or another function that does something similar?

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'order'=> 'DSC' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div>
        <?php $imgs = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
        $attachment = get_posts( $imgs );
        if( $attachment ) {
            the_attachment_link( $attachment[0]->ID , false );
        } ?> 
    </div>
    <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID);
    the_excerpt(); 
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```